# Python Dataframe Tuple to insert data

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

i have the following `tuple` in python `dataframe`:

```
    (array(['2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
        'item1', 10, 2,
        'Promo1', 'NULL'], dtype=object),
 array(['2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
        'item2', 10, 2,
        'Promo1', 'NULL'], dtype=object),
 array(['2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
        'item3', 10, 4,
        'Promo1', 'NULL'], dtype=object),
 array(['2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
        'item4', 10, 4,
        'Promo1', 'NULL'], dtype=object),
 array(['2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
        'item5', 10, 2,
        'Promo1', 'NULL'], dtype=object))
```

i want to transform them to the following output:

```
(
   ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
    'item1', 10, 2,
    'Promo1', 'NULL', ),
   ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
    'item2', 10, 2,
    'Promo1', 'NULL', ),
   ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
    'item3', 10, 4,
    'Promo1', 'NULL', ),
   ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
    'item4', 10, 4,
    'Promo1', 'NULL', ),
   ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01',
    'item5', 10, 2,
    'Promo1', 'NULL', )
)
```

Basically i want to insert all values in dataframe in batch processing (per 5 rows for example)

I am able to utilize `iloc` functions  to have the dataframe in loop.
Now i'm stuck in transforming tuple into expected output.

how do i do that?

Comment: If `a` is one `array` object, `tuple(a)` converts it to a tuple. You just have to iterate through the outer tuple to convert each array.

Comment: `tuple(map(tuple, your_tuple))` it sounds like you're trying to batch commit to a db, have you tried using pandas sql functions?

Comment: cmiiw @cs95 i didn't use pandas sql functions because i am using `psycopg2` which isn't comply with `Pandas` as `Pandas` require `SQLAlchemy` engine

@MichaelButscher the output that i expect is `Insert into some_table values ( (tuple1), (tuple2), (tuple3) ). I want to insert the data per 5k rows for examples

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use :

```
df["new_col"] = [tuple(tuple(x) for x in arr) for arr in df["col"]]
```

Output :

```
print(df.loc[0, "new_col"])

(('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01', 'item1', 10, 2, 'Promo1', 'NULL'),
 ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01', 'item2', 10, 2, 'Promo1', 'NULL'),
 ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01', 'item3', 10, 4, 'Promo1', 'NULL'),
 ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01', 'item4', 10, 4, 'Promo1', 'NULL'),
 ('2023-04-01', '2023-06-01', 'item5', 10, 2, 'Promo1', 'NULL'))
```

*Input used :*

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col": [((np.array(["2023-04-01", "2023-06-01",
            "item1", 10, 2, "Promo1", "NULL"], dtype=object)),
             (np.array(["2023-04-01", "2023-06-01",
            "item2", 10, 2, "Promo1", "NULL"], dtype=object)),
             (np.array(["2023-04-01", "2023-06-01",
            "item3", 10, 4, "Promo1", "NULL"], dtype=object)),
             (np.array(["2023-04-01", "2023-06-01",
            "item4", 10, 4, "Promo1", "NULL"], dtype=object)),
             (np.array(["2023-04-01", "2023-06-01",
            "item5", 10, 2, "Promo1", "NULL"], dtype=object)))]
})
```

Comment: how do i replace `((` to `(` and `))` to `)` in output without parsing into strings and replace them in strings?
my expectation it would comply with query `INSERT INTO some_table VALUES (),(),(),(),()` not `INSERT INTO some_table values ((),(),(),())`